# what permissions do I need to import knowledge from "Data Import Wizard"

Tags: custom-object, permissions, knowledge, data-import-wizard

I have the permission "Import Custom Objects", but cannot see the option "Knowledge" in the data import wizard.

Could someone help me here?

[image: Knowledge Object]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Knowledge User** checkbox on user record.

Comment: Its selected. But no luck!